# Highcharts creating too many values in float

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

The following function which plots a piechart generates too many decimal points while ploting the chart. What should i modify to just make it two decimal points? the code is as given below:

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container2',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Risk Score for countries'
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
            percentageDecimals: 1
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#000000',
                    connectorColor: '#000000',
                    formatter: function() {
                        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ this.percentage +' %';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'pie',
            name: 'Risk Score',
            data: <?php echo json_encode($names1,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>
        }]
    });
});

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
formatter: function() {
    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2); +' %';
}
```

And add it tooltip format, too

```
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
    percentageDecimals: 1,
    formatter: function() {
        return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Highcharts.numberFormat(this.percentage, 2); +' %';
    }
},
```

as [PHP number formats](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pJdhf/)

Comment: it doesnt work. the graph itself is not generated. I tried using this instead of highcharts also

Comment: You mean for example `24.329489 => 24.32` ? if yes, you have two ways. First you can format it in php code. Second, modify your highcharts formattter as my suggestion. (for tooltip and plotOptions)